# How to check the power off time of linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The `last` command shows the list of start/shutdown records. But can not show the Linux power-off time.

Last night, my office powered off unexpectedly, and I want to check the specific time.

[image]

None of the above records does not correspond to the correct time. The correct time from Windows PC:
[image]

2023-5-5 10:40:31

How can I check the time in Linux? thanks.

Comment: You mean there was a loss of power to your office? Are the machines on UPS or do they have some form of battery backup power?

Answer (score 0):

This is not physically possible to log outages. What you could do is run `journalctl` and check messages for the corresponding day and see what was logged last. If you have a good steady stream of log messages this will allow you to approximately pinpoint the outage time, otherwise you've got no options.

Comment: It's possible if you have a UPS and appropriate monitoring software

Comment: Most UPSs are set up such a way when they run out of battery they will shut down your system gracefully which means it's not what the OP is talking about.

Comment: The ones I've used will report when they've lost input power and are running off battery. That's when the timer kicks in and the OS has to guess how long it's got before it will run out of power completely

Answer (score 0):

Journalctl has an option to write logs from volatile to persistent storage. You can check that in `/etc/journald.conf` and search for a line with `Storage=persistent`, then logs should be stored in `/var/log/journal` directory and can be accessed by using

`journalctl -b all` - for all previous and current logs

Also you can use `--since=` and `--until=` options to narrow-down results

Other options are searching for outage using `ausearch` if **auditd** daemon is present on your system

`ausearch -ts [from date] -te [to date]`

if you had other services running on the system, you may also find unpredictable interrupts in their logs

Hope it helps somehow.